# Prevent download of entire remote resource with HttpClient?

Tags: http, uwp, httpclient

Under UWP, the low-level `HttpWebRequest` class and its ilk have been been deprecated, and [the official recommendation](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/) is to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

However, there seems to be either a glaring oversight or a bug in the the `HttpClient` implementation: the API does not seem to provide a way to make a request to a remote URI that does not automatically download the entire remote resource (in the case of a `GET` request) to allow for lazy evaluation of the response stream.

[The documentation for the `HttpClient.GetAsync()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551729(v=vs.118).aspx) says:

> This operation will not block. The returned task object will complete after the whole response (including content) is read.

Which states upfront that the entire remote resource will be downloaded before the request is considered completed. There is an `HttpCompletionOption` parameter which would theoretically allow for working around this if `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is specified, as that is documented as follows:

> The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and headers are read. The content is not read yet.

However, regardless of which `HttpCompletionOption` is specified, in all cases, `HttpClient.GetAsync()` appears to allocate the complete `ContentLength` bytes of the response (in memory! all at once! without any limit checking!) in the process. Naturally, that is somewhat insane and a real problem.

In my particular case, I just want to read the first few kb of a multi-gigabyte remote resource from a server that does not support http range headers. This is normally a "no sweat" operation: just create web request, read from the response stream until you're satisfied, then close the response and be on your merry way.

That does not seem to be an option with the default `HttpClient` API. Is there a simple workaround that does not involve crafting my own HTTP requests using raw sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in all cases, HttpClient.GetAsync() appears to allocate the complete ContentLength bytes of the response (in memory! all at once! without any limit checking!)

This is not true for the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` option.

Just like using the old sweet `HttpWebRequest` class, you can open the response stream and read a few bytes then discard the response. Here is [an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/HttpClient/cs/Scenario2_GetStream.xaml.cs).

Here is my experiment: (I use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient instead, but System.Net.Http.HttpClient provides similar APIs)

```
private HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();


private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri resourceAddress = new Uri("http://somewhere/gigabyte.zip");

    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, resourceAddress);

        // Do not buffer the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(
            request,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);

        using (Stream responseStream = (await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
        {
            int read = 0;
            byte[] responseBytes = new byte[1000];
            do
            {
                read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
                break;
            } while (read != 0);
        }                
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
    }
    finally
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that my test case was borked and did not reliably simulate the `HttpCompletionOptions` values.